# What type of conduit do I need in under ground use?

Tags: wiring

Do you need expansion joints in under ground burial of conduit and what type is acceptable?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need expansion joints underground. For most folks PVC conduit is the easiest to work with. This is different than water pipe but is similar in cutting and glueing. Make sure to chamfer the inside edges of the pipes so they don't cut the insulation when being pulled. I see this step forgotten about quite often.

Comment: Ed,  thanks for your input , I used a schedule 40 conduit gray piping. I hear people talk about a schedule 80, sounds over the top. Never chamfered the piping, is that a big concern. Thought about it after the fact , to late now.

Comment: I have seen wire insulation get cut / shaved off when the pipe has a sharp edge. This is one thing inspectors look at on DIY jobs because most don't know it should be done. It is only on large sizes or pulls with lots of bends that I have seen the insulation dammaged. In 1 case I was called because it kept tripping the supply breaker, I megged it and we pulled the wire out and found about 5' that had damaged insulation when moisture got in the pipe as it always does it started tripping.

Comment: Ed, in this case of cut and shaved insulation were you talking about metal or pvc piping?

Comment: The few times I have been called out to find problems it was PVC, with that said I have had an apprentice not do it on a few pieces of Ridgid one failure when I megged the pull prior to power up and the second 3 months later because vibrations cut through the insulation, really easy to pinpoint when the 480 blows a hole at a coupler he is now a journeyman and chamfers every pipe he touches years later.